# What pattern will distinguish an element of a list from a list when used in a function?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

In Mathematica several versions of a function can have the same name with a pattern distinguishing which version of the function should be used for which type of input. Here is a minimum working example of functions with different names and some test data. (I actually need to work with complicated modules the operation is not relevant. The data structure is relevant.).

```
ClearAll[fred1, fred2];
fred1[a_] := a[[3]];
fred2[a_] := a[[3, 2]];
(* Test data *)
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
a2 = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}};
b1 = {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"};
b2 = {{"s1", "s10"}, {"s2", "s20"}, {"s3", "s30"}, {"s4", "s40"} };
```

When the functions are applied to the test data they works correctly

```
(*  Test functions *)
fred1[a1]
fred2[a2]
fred1[b1]
fred2[b2]


3

30

"s3"

"s30"
```

Now if I want just one function name to do both of the operations given above I can try and distinguish both operations by using a pattern in the function definition.  I can see a way to do this for numbers, but how do you do it for cases which are not numbers?

```
ClearAll[fred];
fred[a_ /; NumberQ[a[[1]]] ] := a[[3]];
fred[a_ /; NumberQ[a[[1, 1]]] ] := a[[3, 2]];

(* Test function *)
fred[a1]
fred[a2]
fred[b1]
fred[b2]
```

[image: Output]

There are probably several ways of defining the pattern to make this work. Some sort of pattern that distinguishes an element of a list from a list. Is there a general way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fred[a_?VectorQ] := a[[3]]

fred[a_?MatrixQ] := a[[3, 2]]

a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
a2 = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}};
b1 = {"s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"};
b2 = {{"s1", "s10"}, {"s2", "s20"}, {"s3", "s30"}, {"s4", "s40"}};

fred /@ {a1, a2, b1, b2}

(* {3, 30, "s3", "s30"} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example this would do the job:

```
fred[a_ /; (NumberQ[a[[1]]] || StringQ[a[[1]]])] := a[[3]];
fred[a_ /; Head[a] == List && (NumberQ[a[[1, 1]]] || StringQ[a[[1, 1]]])] := a[[3,2]];
```

(I added the `StringQ` to the condition to get the same output as in your example)

This would fail for list like `a1 = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};`, but you can also try with `Depth` to check level of nested lists.

Comment: That is helpful. However, a list can contain many types of elements with different types of heads. I don't want to have all sorts of heads questioned. Perhaps look for a head that is not a list?  Depth might be useful.